# C++ file Handling class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, file-handling

I found that I was using the same code over and over again throughout my program.  To improve efficiency etc, I decided that I would impliment a File-Handling class which would allow me to interact with all of my files.

On creating this - I am getting strange errors which I cannot decipher. Eg:

```
Error   11  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\Users\JG\Desktop\ProjectWork\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe   1   1   ConsoleApplication1
```

and

```
Error   8   error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl bolFileExist(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?bolFileExist@@YA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Draw.obj   C:\Users\JG\Desktop\ProjectWork\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Player.obj  ConsoleApplication1
```

I can only put this down to the code in the `Filez.h` file as commenting all of the associated code it builds and runs fine.  I have done some re-search into this and have drawn a blank sadly.

I would very much appreciate some feedback on this code - and some pointers as to what I am doing wrong.

```
string getFinalLineOfFile(string FileLoction)
{
    //http://bit.ly/1j6h6It
    string line = " ";
    string subLine;
    ifstream readFile(FileLoction);
    string found_DrawID; //Username in the file;

    while (getline(readFile,line)) {

    stringstream iss(line);
    //We are only Interested in the First Value 
        iss >> subLine;
    }

    //The Value at CurrentDrawID will be the final value in the file; 
    return subLine;


}
bool bolFileExist(string FileLocation)
{
    //If that Exists. Return it. 
    ifstream readFile(FileLocation);
    return readFile;
}

bool itemExistLineOne(int find, string FileLocation)
{
    string line = " ";
    //ifstream readFile(".//Draws//Draws.txt");
    ifstream readFile(FileLocation);

    string foundID; //Username in the file;

    while (getline(readFile,line)) {

    stringstream iss(line);
    iss >> foundID;

    //Covert the Integer input to a String for comparison.
    if (to_string(find) == foundID) {
            return true;
      } 

    }

    return false; 
}

void CreateNewFileLine(string Location, string text){

    ofstream output_file(Location, ios::app);
    if (!output_file.is_open()) { // check for successful opening
        cout << "Output file could not be opened! Terminating!" << endl;
    }
    else{
    output_file << text;
    output_file << endl; //Create new line at the end of the file. 
    output_file.close();
    }


}
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Make sure these function definitions are in a cpp file and not in a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely missing 'inline' in some header:

```
struct X { void f(); };
inline void X::f() {} // will be multiply defined without inline.
```

End of that header

Comment: Thanks for the Solution - appreciated. What I did was put all of the functions to 'inline' this cleared the problem!